# Remove warning from scala: "It would fail on the following input: Nil"

Tags: scala

I have a scala code.

```
 val lines = Source
        .fromResource("doc-topics-new.txt")
        .getLines
        .toList
        .drop(1) match {
        case x :: xs => x.split(" ").drop(2).mkString(" ") :: xs
      }
```

when I run the code it is working how ever there is a warning message

```
Warning:(81, 14) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Nil
        .drop(1) match {
```

Please suggest how to remove this warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a case of `Nil`:

```
val lines = Source
        .fromResource("doc-topics-new.txt")
        .getLines
        .toList
        .drop(1) match {
        case Nil => List.empty   // Add this line
        case x :: xs => x.split(" ").drop(2).mkString(" ") :: xs
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the `Nil` case to your pattern matching.

if you really wanna suppress the warning you could use the [unchecked](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/unchecked.html) annotation:

```
val lines = (Source
        .fromResource("doc-topics-new.txt")
        .getLines
        .toList
        .drop(1): @unchecked) match {
        case x :: xs => x.split(" ").drop(2).mkString(" ") :: xs
      }
```

Comment: Using this annotation is dangerous and can cause a runtime exception. A safer way is to add the `Nil` case